# Error: 1265 : Data truncated for column exploded string

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am fairly new at any type of programming. I would say, I've been involved for roughly 6-8 months, so please forgive me if I am asking a silly question or using the wrong terminology.

I am working on a school assignment for a MySQL class. It is a simple web application for a video store. I've created a very simple form whose data should get posted to the sql database. So far, I've been successful. However, I am attempting to pass two values from a single radio button selection to two separate fields in a database table. I've attempted to use PHP's explode() function and then use the variable holding the resulting array in the SQL insert statement. So far I've been unsuccessful.

I get the following three errors:

1.) Notice: Undefined index: rtx[0] in C:\wamp64\www\Final_Project\rent.php on line 38

2.) Notice: Undefined index: rtx[1] in C:\wamp64\www\Final_Project\rent.php on line 38

3.) Error: 1265 : Data truncated for column 'Rental_fee' at row 1

*Row 38 is the row containing the sql insert statement*

**The HTML for the form(radio buttons)**.

```
 <div class="form-group"> 
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Rental type</label> 
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      New release <input name="Rental_type" type="radio" value="6.99,2.99" checked="checked" action="">
      Standard <input name="Rental_type" type="radio" value="4.99,1.99" action="">
    </div>
```

**I then attempted to pass the value to a variable in order to use the explode function.**

```
enter $rt = $_POST['Rental_type']; 
$rtx = explode(',',$rt);
```

**Finally, the sql insert statement.**

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO rental_table (Cust_id, Movie_id, Check_out_date, Return_due_date, Rental_fee, Per_diem_late_fee, Last_updated) VALUES ('{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Cust_id'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Movie_id'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Check_out_date'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Return_due_date'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['rtx[0]'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['rtx[1]'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Last_updated'])}')";


 $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);




 // Print response from MySQL
  if ( $insert ) {
    echo "Success!";
  } else {
    die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
  }

  // Close our connection
  $mysqli->close();
```

I've been a longtime lurker, first time posting. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Rather than code your values into the radio, code the radios so that the value you pass back only tells you what type you are looking at. Then in your php, pull the monetary values from an array based on what the radio button sent to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$_POST['rtx[0]']` but you haven't got any index like that in the POST variable so instead, use `$rtx[0]` as below:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO rental_table (
    Cust_id, Movie_id, Check_out_date, Return_due_date, Rental_fee, Per_diem_late_fee, Last_updated
) VALUES (
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Cust_id'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Movie_id'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Check_out_date'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Return_due_date'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($rtx[0])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($rtx[1])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Last_updated'])}'
)";
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you. I also sanitized the value being passed into the variable $rt, which I then used to pass into the explode function. I'm not entirely sure if it is necessary; however, I've reached the intended purpose.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this out instead:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Rental type</label> 
<div class="col-sm-4">
  New release <input name="Rental_type" type="radio" value="new" checked="checked" action="">
  Standard <input name="Rental_type" type="radio" value="std" action="">
</div>
```

now, you need to add an array of values to call into your php.

```
$var =  array(
    'std' => array ('4.99', '1.99'),
    'new' => array ('6.99', '2.99')
);
```

Now, you get your post var and call out the values from the array.

```
$val1 = $var[$_POST['Rental_Type'][0];
$val2 = $var[$_POST['Rental_Type'][1];
```

--do something with it.

Eventually, you are going to be extracting these kinds of values from a database or data file somewhere, might as well start working that way now.